# C# combine two lists without duplicates and keep same order

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I know that a lot of answers on how to combine two lists and remove the duplicates. However i can't find a solution where the order of the elements is not changed. Maybe the code below will help you better what i want to do.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 5, 12, 13, 9, 8, 14, 4, 15 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 12, 6, 7, 13, 8, 9, 14, 2, 3, 15 };
List<int> ulist = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

I want this output: 1, 5, 12, 6, 7, 13, 8, 9, 14
The reason I want this kind of sorting is this:

```
//  list1 - list2   desired output
//    1   -   1          1
//    5   -              5
//   12   -  12         12
//        -   6          6 
//        -   7          7 
//   13   -  13         13 
//    9   -   8          8  
//    8   -   9          9 
//   14   -  14         14 
//        -   2          2
//        -   3          3
//    4   -              4
//   15   -   15        15
```

The order should be the same as the second list for numbers that exist in both lists but are not in the same order. Like for example for 6 and 7 in this example

For situation like we have with the numbers 2, 3 and 4 where the numbers from the second list should be added first

Maybe I should add that I need solution that will work on any 2 lists of integers not only for the examples above.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: The order isn't changed there either: all the elements from `list1` are in the same order as they were in the original list, and then you have the unique elements of `list2` after that.

Comment: Did you try doing `list2.Union(list1).ToList(); `

Comment: @Chetan yes I did but still didn't get my desired output

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes I understand this but that is not what I want. My desired output is in the question

Comment: If you don't have a key to sort by, then create one. `.Select((item, index) =>new { item, index})`. And re-sort the list at the end.

Comment: What if you have lists 1,2,4,5 and 1,5,4, what should be the order? Can you put the merge rule to words?

Comment: `from item in list1.Union(list2) let ordering1 = list1.IndexOf(item) let ordering2 = list2.IndexOf(item) orderby ordering1 descending , ordering2 descending select item` or something similar

Comment: @GuruStron, for 1,2,4,5 and 1,5,4 the output should be 1,2,5,4. The order should be taken from list 2 (in this case: 1,5,4). The order should be the same as the second list for numbers that exist in both lists but are not in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write some custom logic to handle this; there is no built in Linq query you can use because this problem is specific to your domain. The "order" of the items in your lists relative to one another is subjective, and you have given no clarity on how this order should be inferred, which is why your question has been downvoted.

Assuming that your rule is...

1. if an element is common to both lists then it will be in the same position in each list relative to every other common element
2. when merged this order should be preserved
3. when merged, any element that appears in only one list should maintain its position relative to the common elements

... I've taken a crack at it. Here is some code that will solve this specific problem with these specific lists:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 12, 6, 7, 13 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 5, 12, 13 };

var output = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0, j = 0; ;)
{
    int? item1 = i < list1.Count ? list1[i] : null; 
    int? item2 = j < list2.Count ? list2[j] : null;
    
    if (item1 is null && item2 is null)
        break;
    
    if (item1 == item2)
    {
        output.Add(item1.Value);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if (list1.Contains(item2.Value))
    {
        output.Add(item1.Value);
        i++;
    }
    else if (list2.Contains(item1.Value))
    {
        output.Add(item2.Value);
        j++;
    }
}

foreach (var i in output)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Output:

```
1
5
12
6
7
13
```

Given the limited scope of this solution, I expect it will be buggy when passed different input data. You will need to test it and modify it to fix any bugs and further suit your needs.

One obvious edge case is two uncommon elements in the same relative position (e.g. `1, 12, 6, 7, 13` and `1, 5, 12, 8, 13`) -- how should the 6, 7 and 8 be positioned relative to one another in the output?

This solution will also not scale well as the input lists grow (and the number of uncommon values increases) due to the need to look up each uncommon value in the other list.

Comment: for (e.g. 1, 12, 6, 7, 13 and 1, 5, 12, 8, 13), should be (1, 5, 13, 8, 6, 7, 13). The numbers from the second list should be added first.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct because it answers my original question. However there has been some edits because i forgot to mention some things in my original question and that is my fault. If u have any time and will you can check them. Nonetheless thanks a lot, this will be good starting point.